# Space as grouping separator in printf

Tags: java

I know how to use comma in `printf` as grouping separator to print value in format like
`1,000,000.00`

to print it that way I'm using command

`System.out.printf ("%,.2f", value);`

but how to use space as grouping separator to format value like
`1 000 000.00`

I tried to find solution but solutions with using `DecimalFormat` look at now to complicate for me (beginner level). 
**Is there as easy way as in example with comma to do it**?

Comment: As far as I know %s is used to print string. In example above I want to print float value but in format where grouping separator is space

Comment: The formatting you're looking at is locale dependent. However, space and period is a strange mix of US (. as comma) and European (space as grouping) formatting. But it won't be as confusing as getting "." and "," wrong though ;o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fast answer:

```
String result = String.format("%,.2f", value).replace(".", " ");
System.out.println(result);
```

(assuming you are using Java 1.5 or above).

Using `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
String.format(symbols.getGroupingSeparator(), ' ')
```

or even better:

```
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
f = new DecimalFormat("###,###.00", symbols);
System.out.println(f.format(value));
```

Comment: Note that the fast `replace()` answer doesn't have the desired outcome for all locales. The period `.` denotes a decimal seperator in one locale and a grouping character in another locale.

Answer (score 1):

Printf doesnt handle this. Use println insted. Example from [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormatSymbols unusualSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
unusualSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('|');
unusualSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('^');

String strange = "#,##0.###";
DecimalFormat weirdFormatter = new DecimalFormat(strange, unusualSymbols);
weirdFormatter.setGroupingSize(4);

String bizarre = weirdFormatter.format(12345.678);
System.out.println(bizarre);

out : 1^2345|678
```

To convert Float to String:

println uses [FloatingDecimal](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html)

printf uses [FormattedFloatingDecimal](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FormattedFloatingDecimal.java.html)

But I haven't time to look deeper why these classes are different. Enjoy reading :)

Comment: "Weird" example but I think I understand it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna do it you should use the Decimalformat
this would be your solution

> DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#0,000.00");
>
> f.format(13000);

A little bit explenation over here:
the amount of zeros after the comma will give you the amount of numbers the DecimalFormat will insert a dot in there. The amount of zeros after the dot is the amount of decimals the DecimalFormat will write

EDIT: oh i just saw you wanted to have spaces in there:

because f.format will return a String you can simply add the `.replace("\\.", " ");`

Method. this will replace all the dots written in there with a space

Comment: I understand it and it works fine but for comma. When I try to change comma into space `' '` `#0 000.00` it doesnt work. Shows output without grouping separator like `1000000.00`

Comment: see the answers below, they allready intreduced into the DecimalFormatSymbols

Comment: even so this one
`DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0,000.00");

DecimalFormatSymbols d =  f.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

d.setGroupingSeparator(' ');

f.setDecimalFormatSymbols(d);

String t = f.format(3000000);

System.out.println(t);`