# Can anyone help me remove the comma from my output?

Tags: java

So my code is correctly outputting the compounded interest periodically, but it is putting my output with a comma. Ex: $1,000.00 I would like the answer to be: $1000.00.

Here is my code guys:

```java
package certificatedeposit;

public class CertificateDeposit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double PV = 1000.00;

         System.out.printf("Enter annual rate: ");
          java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner( System.in );
            double rate = in.nextDouble( );
              double rates = rate / 100 / 12; 

         System.out.printf("Enter CD term in months: ");
            int months = in.nextInt( );

        double product = ( 1 + rates);
        double exp = Math.pow(product,months);
        double fv = PV * exp;

        System.out.printf("An initial investment of $1000.00 after "+months+" months at annual rate of %,.2f%% is $%,.2f \n", rate, fv);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: It's printing a comma because you told it to print a comma.  That's what the `,` character after % does.  Lose it.  If you don't understand format strings, read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: thank u soo much. stupid mistake on my part guys.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the code for you but as @ajb said in comment, you are getting "," because you have used it while formatting string. For deep understanding read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

```
package certificatedeposit;

public class CertificateDeposit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double PV = 1000.00;

         System.out.printf("Enter annual rate: ");
          java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner( System.in );
            double rate = in.nextDouble( );
              double rates = rate / 100 / 12; 

         System.out.printf("Enter CD term in months: ");
            int months = in.nextInt( );

        double product = ( 1 + rates);
        double exp = Math.pow(product,months);
        double fv = PV * exp;

   System.out.printf("An initial investment of $1000.00 after "+months+" months at annual rate of %,.2f%% is $%.2f \n", rate, fv);

    }

}
```

Comment: To both of you guys - much much thanks. What a stupid mistake on my part. Thank you guys, really help the quick feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the format string for variable `fv`:

```
System.out.printf("An initial investment of $1000.00 after "+months+" months at annual rate of %,.2f%% is $%.2f \n", rate, fv);
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306791/space-as-grouping-separator-in-printf) is a discussion about using different (not only comma) symbols for grouping separator.